# how to switch from collection view(grid view) to table view(list view) using a button?

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview

In this already I had implemented the collection view needs to invalidate the layout and need to implement the table view(list view) when i select a button the image is as shown below

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to implement this in swift 3?

[image: This image]

This image mentioned is already implemented in code now I need to change to as mentioned in above image.

Comment: Do you want to implement view like bottom image?

Comment: no top image bottom image already implemented @AbhishekJain

Comment: i am having a button on top f i click on it then it need to change to table view(list view) @AbhishekJain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import UIKit 
      class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.alpha = 0
    collectionView.alpha = 1
```

}

```
@IBAction func Button1(_ sender: Any) {
    
    tableView.alpha = 0
    collectionView.alpha = 1
}

@IBAction func Button2(_ sender: Any) {
    
    tableView.alpha = 1
    collectionView.alpha = 0

}
// Table View
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
    
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.lblName.text = "dd "
    cell.lblreview.text = " fff"
    return cell
}
//Collection View

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: i had tried wat u said but i got this error when i click on a button and the error is this 2017-08-01 16:30:57.639 Ecommerce[6043:141264] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier productsCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' @Subojit Mandal

Answer (score 1):

Using Collectionview :- Easy way to change gridview to listview or vice verca.

Make two layouts

```
private lazy var listCVLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30)
collectionFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 80)
collectionFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
collectionFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
collectionFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    return collectionFlowLayout
}()

private lazy var gridCVLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {


let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
collectionFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30)
collectionFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (SCREEN_WIDTH - 80) / 2 , height: SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.16)
collectionFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
collectionFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
    return collectionFlowLayout
}()
```

and finally when toggle view use this

```
  self.listCV.startInteractiveTransition(to: isListView ? self.listCVLayout : self.gridCVLayout, completion: nil)
  self.listCV.finishInteractiveTransition()
```

Comment: When to call start startInteractiveTransition and  finishInteractiveTransition Please explain in details

Answer (score 0):

Add  tableViewDelegate

```
     class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
```

Now Add three protocol

```
     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return item_name.count
}



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MedicineTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MedicineTableViewCell


        cell.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnHide), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.btnAdd.tag = indexPath.row




    return cell
}
```

This for when your cell is clicked

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

This for when your Button is clicked

```
    func BtnHide(sender: UIButton) {

          print(sender.tag)

       }
```

Dont forget to connect datasource and delegate from your table view to ViewController in your storyboard

Comment: no not like this i am having button if i click on it my collection view layout needs to be altered and change to first mentioned image @Subhojit Mandal

Comment: then there is no problem with collection view when i place a table view on it ?@Subhojit Mandal

Comment: http://zappdesigntemplates.com/collectionview-flow-layout-from-grid-to-list-layout/ like this i need is it able to get with ur code ?

Comment: Not understanding your exact problem can you provide more info

Comment: i had already implemented the collection view as shown in second image now when i click on a button in the same screen then in the same screen i need to display table view design as shown in first image without changing any data @Subhojit Mandal

Comment: okk there are two ways of doing this ...first you can change the layout of collection view .Set the width of the collectionview to be equal to view or collectionview width or you can use use containerview or two separate view and on click on that you set the alpha of one to 0 and other to 1 and vise vera

Comment: any one way just tell me how to implement it @Subhojit Mandal

Comment: make outlet of your collection view and table view .

Comment: on click of button click   tableview.alpha = 0 and collectionview.alpha = 1

Comment: collection view layout is better for performance or placing in container view is better @Subhojit Mandal

Answer (score 0):

add this UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


    if self.varname == "Collection" { 
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width*0.47, height: self.view.frame.height*0.21)
  }else{

   return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 
   self.view.frame.height*0.21)
 }

}
```

Comment: but if i use this code can i get the product name and price on other side

Comment: that means image should be on left and name price and button should be placed on right is it possible with this ? @Subhojit Mandal

Answer (score 0):

**Another Way**

```
@IBAction func action_ChangeLayoutCV(_ sender: Any) {
    isListView.toggle()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collHomeUpcoming.reloadData()
        self.collHomeUpcoming.setCollectionViewLayout(self.isListView ? self.listCVLayout : self.gridCVLayout, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```